# How do I get one constructor to fire multiple tooltips?

Tags: tippyjs

I am trying to get one button to fire multiple tippy elements at once. I have created a each of the `tippy()` instances, but it does not work.

```
<span class="btn btn-success show-tooltip">test</span>

<span class="test-one" data-tippy-content="This is tooltip">Text</span>
<span class="test-two" data-tippy-content="This is another tooltip">Text</span>

<script>
tippy('.test-one', {
    triggerTarget: '.show-tooltip'
});

tippy('.test-two', {
    triggerTarget: '.show-tooltip'
});
</script>
```

But doing so doesn't fire the tooltip.